# How do I get a clickable link for this?

Tags: php

```
<li>Your download link <?php echo "http://mysite.com/superupload/upload/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]; ?>
```

Okay well that's the code that I got and yeah it displays the file url but if I go to the url it displays an image if I upload an image which is great BUT I want it to be downloadable rather than viewable. Also I could do with the echo being a clickable echo link.

Hope you understand what I mean I basically want it a clickable link to down the file.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an anchor tag? You're not really asking that right?

Comment: "Hope you understand what I mean". Nope.

Comment: Look up A anchor tags in HTML and look up header function in php

Comment: OP is not good in English but his question is still understandable and totally legit, why some many downvotes?

Comment: Lol OP IS English and yes the question was simple enough..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li><a href="<?php echo "http://mysite.com/superupload/upload/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]; ?>"> Your download link </a></li>
```

might do it...

Comment: You didn't close your tag ;) You have <a href="" Your download link</a>

Comment: Tried that eidsonator just doesn't show anything >.<

Comment: As David pointed out, the anchor tag was not closed... I've fixed it.  it was the > after the last quote.

Comment: The edit worked eidsonator and it is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks guys it worked :)